# Can plants be grown successfully from the seeds in a kitchen cupboard?

Tags: indoors, seeds, herbs, germination

In my kitchen cupboard I have the usual herbs and spices (e.g. coriander seeds, cardamom, dried chilies, celery seeds etc. - your typical collection of Schwartz jars) and I want to know if it's possible to grow plants from these - i.e. could I grow a successful crop of coriander from dried coriander seeds?

If it is possible, what kind of store cupboard herbs spices can I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet would be to try germinating them using a damp paper towel.  If they sprout, you're good to go.  It probably varies based on how old the seeds are and how they were dried, etc.

Comment: This is really the only way of knowing for sure. You don't know how old the seeds are; some seeds are smoked for flavor (and not likely viable); some are dried with heat. The idea of preserving spices for your cupboard is to draw out much of the moisture, which is at odds with the viability of finding fresher seed stock to grow your plants. Incidentally, if you grow coriander seeds, you'll get cilantro.

Answer (score 1):

Coriander seeds. I cracked these open and spreaded the seeds in my soil. It is now growing as little seedlings. I want to see how many will come up. We have tropical climate so it was easy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but the viability depends on the type of seed,age of seed and the processes they have been subjected to.  (Heat, for example can kill the seeds)  I've recently germinated Goji Berries this way.  Beans are very commonly grown.